# Staircase problem in Python - How to list all the ways to climb a staircase of N steps

Tags: python, list, recursion, permutation

I have the following question related to the staircase problem: There is a staircase with N steps, and you can climb 1 or 3 steps a time. Write a function climbcombination(N) which return the all the combination of steps to climb the staircase.

Expected output:

```
climbcombination(4) return ['1111', '13', '31']
```

I have difficulties in solving this problem because the function can only take one argument. Any help is really appreciated.

This is the function that I have written for counting the total number of combination to climb up the ladder

```
def climbNo(N):
if N == 1:
    return 1
if N == 2:
    return 1
if N == 3:
    return 2
else:
    return climbNo(N-1) + climbNo(N-3)
```

In attempting to print all the combination to climb up the stairs. This is what I have written.

```
def climbcombination(N):
result = []
if N == 1:
    step = '1'
    result.append(step)
if N == 2:
```

May I know how can I use the (if N==1 statement) to let the function to return ['11'] when N = 2? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hint: If I've already calculated climbcombination(n-1) and climbcombination(n-3) for you, could you use my result to calculate climbcombination(n)?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't know how to do that. I know how to calculate the total number of ways to climb up the staircase but found it difficult to print the combination out one by one.

Comment: there's quite a difference between "I found it difficult" and "I don't know at all". Calculating the total number of ways to climb up the staircase is a very good start. If you can write code that does that, do it. Then you can try to adapt that code to return the combinations instead of the number.

Comment: I have written the code counting the total number of combination to walk up the stairs but I still stuck at the part on how to make a list containing all the combination. May I have some more hints on that. Really appreciate your help!!